# Select2 choices are not not visible

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

I have a problem with select2 jquery. When i click on input box the list items are not visible (their height is very small). I tried but did not find any sollution.

```
$("#e1").select2({ dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop"});
```

And the HTML code is as bellow.

```
<select id="e1" multiple style="width: 300px;">
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
                        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
                        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
                        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>
```

I'm using admin theme from netdreams.co.uk.
On simple page it works but on admin theme it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if you have CSS for bigdrop

Answer (score 0):

The admin theme was reseting the body font-size to 0. Therefore I was unable to see the choice. :P